# Does RHEL 6 enforce software constraints on the number of SATA drvices that can exist on a system?

Tags: rhel, hard-disk, sata

I came across the following blurb in some RHEL 6 training documentation:

> The number of drives that can be installed on modern computers has increased.  With port multipliers, it's relatively easy to configure 16 Serial Advanced Technology Attachment (SATA) drives on a system (assuming you can fit all of those drives).

Does this mean that RHEL 6 won't allow more than 16 SATA drives from a software perspective? Or just that practical hardware constraints usually don't allow for more than 16 but it's technically possible?

Comment: I have personally used 36 SATA drive chassis in RHEL/CentOS 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL's limitations are core- and RAM-based, not drive count-based; the wording is hinting at few chassis being able to mount more than 10 or so drives. Linux itself is limited to 128 SCSI drive devices (`sda` through `sddx`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That interesting - the training documentation also mentions that "depending on the SCSI hardware available, you can attach up to 31 different SCSI hard drive".  I wonder where they got that number?

Comment: That refers specifically to [SCSI interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI#Interfaces) hard drives. [`sdX` devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI#SCSI_command_protocol) include PATA, SATA, USB, etc. interface hard drives as well.

Comment: Another note is that a hardware RAID array is seen by the OS as a single SCSI device.